# How do I differentiate between two countries with the same country code using libPhoneNumber-iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using libPhoneNumber-iOS (https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS) to parse international phone numbers, and I am having a bit of trouble differentiating between different countries with the same country code (e.g. USA and Canada both use +1).  Does anyone know if this library does this?

Here is the code I'm using to retrieve the country code (region code i.e. "US"):

```
let fullPhoneNumber = "+15065552222"

guard let phoneUtil = NBPhoneNumberUtil.sharedInstance() else {
    return "error"
}

do {
    let phoneNumber = try phoneUtil.parse(fullPhoneNumber, defaultRegion: "ZZ")

    return phoneUtil.getRegionCode(forCountryCode: phoneNumber.countryCode)
    
} catch {
    return "error"
}
```

This code returns "US" for the country code, even though it is a Canadian number.  Does anyone know what I can do to get the accurate country using this library?

Comment: Check also the area code? Here is a list of [Canada Area Codes](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-differentiate-a-Canadian-phone-number-from-an-American-phone-number)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I can write logic to check area codes.  I don't want to have to do that for all countries with matching country codes.  I'd like to have it done through the library if it's possible.

Comment: I looked through the Github issues, some users can successfully identify the Canadian phone number: https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS/issues/124

Comment: Thanks @Raptor! Unfortunately that user didn't say what resolved the issue :(